# Memory size exhausted when trying to update Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 through putty

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, memory

I'm trying to update my Magento 2.3.0 installation to Magento 2.3.1. I'm trying to do this through putty, but when I try to do "composer update" I get this error:

```
- magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///home/customer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it to use as much memory as it wants with:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

Comment: I'm on siteground, on shared hosting, and I tried that, but still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try running composer without a memory limit

Get the path to composer executable

```
which composer
```

Run composer from php, disabling the memory limit:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

### Update 1

Based on your comments and new error, it looks like you are running out of actual memory on a shared hosting environment. The php flag mentioned above just disabled the soft memory limit through php.

This is a long shot, but is there an admin panel for your hosting that lets you manage resources at all for this site? It seems doubtful.

Something else you could do, but would involve a little bit of down time:

1. Make a backup of the database on the environment it's failing for. Anonymize the data in the backup.
2. Run the upgrade commands on a local environment that you control memory for, with or without the backup of the database. The initial attempt of this is just to confirm the upgrade works without errors.
3. Put the environment with memory limitation into maintenance mode.
4. Make another backup of the database
5. Run the upgrade again on the local environment
6. Place the upgraded code and database back on the environment.
7. Disable maintenance mode.

This comes with some risks as you might not be able to test everything from the upgrade locally. Also not a great idea to bring the database local if it has production customer data. Make sure crons are not running and no processes that would send emails or notify customers are running.

Comment: Still no, tried and getting this: Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1725968384) (tried to allocate 75497472 bytes) in phar:///home/customer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 73

Comment: I was going to ask if you are on shared hosting. Looks like you are from your comment on another answer. That error looks like you are actually running out of memory on the shared hosting.

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately I can't even get more memory, I have asked the hosting company to give me te resources just to do the update, but nothing.. and that's a problem as I need to update to 2.3.3 as php7.2 won't be supported anymore with the new year, so basically need that version so I can use php7.3

Comment: See my updated answer. Maybe not feasible but you could do the update off server then transfer everything back. Would involve some downtime/maintenance mode during the actual running of the upgrade against a copy of the schema/database. This memory limit issue is largely due to composer v1. Projects I have worked on run into that memory limit more and more and almost always require the commands i mentioned to disable/increase the limit. Good news is composer v2 is way faster/better about this, but not fully supported until Magento 2.4.3